# Varnish - HTTP/1.0 response served as HTTP/1.1

Tags: http, http-headers, varnish

I am trying to get HTTP 1.0 response for this request:

```
 curl -v -A "VLSub" -0 http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc
*   Trying 92.240.234.122...
* Connected to api.opensubtitles.org (92.240.234.122) port 80 (#0)
> GET /xml-rpc HTTP/1.0
> Host: api.opensubtitles.org
> User-Agent: VLSub
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control
< Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 04:19:36 GMT
< X-Cache-Backend: web2
< X-Cache: MISS
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 305
< Connection: close
< Age: 0
< 
* Closing connection 0
[data]
```

varnishd (varnish-4.1.3 revision 5e3b6d2):

```
*   << BeReq    >> 399913921 
-   Begin          bereq 399913920 pass
-   Timestamp      Start: 1477887576.236176 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /xml-rpc
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: api.opensubtitles.org
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: VLSub
-   BereqHeader    Accept: */*
-   BereqHeader    If-Modified-Since: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 04:18:26 GMT
-   BereqHeader    Cache-Control: max-stale=0
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 399913921
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    922 14.web2 172.20.100.2 80 172.20.10.253 60531
-   BackendStart   172.20.100.2 80
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1477887576.236208 0.000032 0.000032
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1477887576.244435 0.008259 0.008227
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.0
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   BerespHeader   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
-   BerespHeader   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control
-   BerespHeader   Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 305
-   BerespHeader   Connection: close
-   BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 04:19:36 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Lighttpd 1.4.x
-   TTL            RFC 120 10 -1 1477887576 1477887576 1477887576 0 0
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   BerespUnset    Server: Lighttpd 1.4.x
-   BerespHeader   X-Cache-Backend: web2
-   TTL            VCL 120 10 0 1477887576
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   ObjHeader      Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
-   ObjHeader      Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control
-   ObjHeader      Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
-   ObjHeader      Content-Length: 305
-   ObjHeader      Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 04:19:36 GMT
-   ObjHeader      X-Cache-Backend: web2
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   BackendClose   922 14.web2
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1477887576.244481 0.008305 0.000046
-   Length         305
-   BereqAcct      218 0 218 373 305 678
-   End
```

Added Varnish response (upgraded Varnish to 5.0.0)

```
# varnishlog -q "ReqHeader ~ 'xxx.6.249.201' and ReqHeader ~ 'VLSub'"
*   << Request  >> 983658552 
-   Begin          req 983658551 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1478109092.896425 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1478109092.896425 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       xxx.6.249.201 60135
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /xml-rpc
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: api.opensubtitles.org
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: VLSub
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      If-Modified-Since: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 17:47:21 GMT
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-stale=0
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: xxx.6.249.201
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     pass
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 983658553 pass
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1478109092.904685 0.008260 0.008260
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.0
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control
-   RespHeader     Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 305
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 17:51:32 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-Backend: web3
-   RespUnset      HTTP/1.0
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 983658552
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 983658552
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1478109092.904700 0.008274 0.000014
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1478109092.904718 0.008292 0.000018
-   ReqAcct        188 0 188 422 305 727
-   End
```

it should work. But why curl is getting HTTP 1.1 response? I see Varnish is serving HTTP/1.0 responses. Thanks with any help

Comment: this is expected.  Servers and proxies emit the http version they use/understand, rather than reflecting back the client's version.  Why in particular do you want the version stamp in the response to indicate HTTP/1.0?  The server/proxy will already be altering behaviour based on the version of the request (default connection mode = close rather than keep-alive, no chunking etc)

Comment: The logs you are sharing are the logs corresponding to the backend request (`bereq`) and response (`beresp`), not the client response.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann how to get client response (if there is any)? I provide CURL response from server, and VARNISH log.

Comment: @Adrien some of clients of our API have problem with transfer-encoding: chunked. Here is description one of them (and couple of others are failing for exactly same reason): github.com/exebetche/vlsub/issues/143

Comment: In the varnishlog you sent there is only the backend request and response log (399913921). Just afterwards in your varnishlog you should see the client request and response (399913920). `<< BeReq >> 399913921 - Begin bereq 399913920 pass`

Comment: As for chunked transfer, check that do_stream is set to false

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann ok, i dumped the response headers. I dont understand, why I see there RespUnset      HTTP/1.0. I checked config, I dont have anything like that there. For chunked encoding - it is adding CloudFlare automatically, when there is HTTP/1.1 response, and they wrote me, HTTP/1.0 response will not add it there.

Comment: no server should send chunked response to an http/1.0 request, but if the request is http/1.1 then the responder is free to assume that chunked encoding is supported.  Are these troublesome clients that dont' support chunking sending http./1,1 requests?  Sounds like they should be fixed, rather than varnish broken to support them.

Comment: @Adrien you are right, they will fix it. But some of them are running on devices and there will be not a new firmware (or there is problem with updates), so I am looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varnish is definitely responding with HTTP 1.1 protocol :

```
-   RespUnset      HTTP/1.0
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
```

Varnish seems to do it default wise (see https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/641 )

You can try to override this in the vcl_deliver, resp.proto is writable (see https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vcl.html#resp )

```
set resp.proto = "HTTP/1.0"
```

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you. This is working. Now I set in PHP X-HTTP-Version header as needed, and then in VCL I am processing it: 
if(resp.http.X-HTTP-Version == "1.0") {
        set resp.proto = "HTTP/1.0";
  }